# Segue between SKScene and UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, swift3, segue

I'm writing simple math game with swift 3 and I have a problem with segues. I have two `GameViewController's`, one`UIViewController` and one `NavigationViewController`.[image]

I want to make two menus, one with game modes and one with difficulties, I want that the difficulties menu be interactive and have gravity so I decided to make it in SkScene. Everything works fine except segue between SkScene with dark screen and difficulties menu when user lost the game. I write a protocol which works when I'm going from main menu to second menu but when I'm going from SkScene with game it doesn't. I was trying to make a manual segue but protocol doesn't want to execute. [image]

MyGVViewController code:

```
    import UIKit
    import SpriteKit
    import GameplayKit

    enum skad1 {
     case game,menu
     }
    var skad = skad1.gra

    class MyGVViewController: UIViewController, GameViewControllerDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
        // Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'
        if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "Menugame") {
            let gameScene = scene as! MySKScene
            gameScene.gameViewControllerDelegate = self
            gameScene.scaleMode = .aspectFill


            gameScene.size = view.bounds.size

            // Present the scene
            view.presentScene(gameScene)
        }

        view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        view.showsFPS = true
        view.showsNodeCount = true
    }
}

override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
    return true
}

override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
        return .allButUpsideDown
    } else {
        return .all
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}

func goback() {
    print("goback executed")
    let view = self.view as! SKView?
    view?.presentScene(nil)
    navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

}
func goback2() {
    print("goback2 executed")
    let view = self.view as! SKView?
    view?.presentScene(nil)
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "comeback", sender: nil)
}

}
```

My SkScene with difficulties menu code:

```
 import GameKit
 import SpriteKit
 import CoreMotion

 protocol GameViewControllerDelegate: class {
    func goback()
    func goback2()
 }



class MySKScene: SKScene {

//Variables

var motionManager: CMMotionManager!
var ball = SKSpriteNode()
var ball1 = SKSpriteNode()
var ball2 = SKSpriteNode()
var ball3 = SKSpriteNode()
var ball4 = SKSpriteNode()
weak var gameViewControllerDelegate: GameViewControllerDelegate?

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        if ball.contains(location){
            showgame(zakres: 200)
        }else if ball1.contains(location){
            showgame(zakres: 100)
        }else if ball2.contains(location) {
            showgame(zakres: 50)
        }else if ball3.contains(location) {
            showgame(zakres: 150)
        }else if ball4.contains(location) {
            if skad == .menu{
                print("should execut goback")
                self.gameViewControllerDelegate?.goback()
            }else{
                print("should execut goback2")
                self.gameViewControllerDelegate?.goback2()
            }
        }
    }
}

func showgame(zakres:Int) {

    if let view = self.view {
        range = zakres
        // Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'
        if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
            // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
            let gameScene = scene as! GameScene
            gameScene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

            // Present the scene
            gameScene.size = view.bounds.size
            view.presentScene(gameScene)
        }

        view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        view.showsFPS = true
        view.showsNodeCount = true
    }
}



override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    ball = self.childNode(withName: "ball") as! SKSpriteNode
    ball1 = self.childNode(withName: "ball1") as! SKSpriteNode
    ball2 = self.childNode(withName: "ball2") as! SKSpriteNode
    ball3 = self.childNode(withName: "ball3") as! SKSpriteNode
    ball4 = self.childNode(withName: "ball4") as! SKSpriteNode
    motionManager = CMMotionManager()
    motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdates()
    let border = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: self.frame)
    border.friction = 0
    border.restitution = 0
    self.physicsBody = border
}


override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    if let accelerometerData = motionManager.accelerometerData {
        physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: accelerometerData.acceleration.x * 20, dy: accelerometerData.acceleration.y * 35)
    }
}
```

}

PS.
I'm reading what I wrote and I have to correct it, in difficulties menu I have a button which execute protocol that hide SKScene and show main menu. It works only when I'm going from main menu but when segue is from game when user lost, protocol isn't executed

Comment: Try to stick to one view controller and multiple scenes. That is how SpriteKit games are meant to function in a first place. You will likely experience even more issues in a future by going this way. I dont say it is impossible to fix this. I just say it is not recommended.

Comment: But if you want to fix your issue, I would start with checking your new delegate to see if it is somehow nil. I havent really looked into all your code (will look later) but that is the first thing I would check.

Comment: I'm reading what I wrote and I have to correct it, in difficulties menu I have a button which execute protocol that hide SKScene and show main menu. It works only when I'm going from main menu but when segue is from game when user lost, protocol isn't executed